# Interrelated binomial distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X$ follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ and $Y$ follows a binomial distribution with parameters $m$ and $p$.Then if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $r$,$s\geq 0$,  show that-----
$$P(X=r\mid X+Y=r+s)=\frac{\binom{m}{r} \cdot  \binom{m}{s}}{\binom{m+n}{r+s}}$$

I have tried many problems on binomial distribution but have no idea on this type of questions where the parameters of binomial distribution are interrelated.

Please help me out with a general way to proceed such problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$X+Y$ is a binomial distribution. Can you figure out the parameters?

Also,
\begin{align}
P(X=r|X+Y=r+s)&=\frac{P(X=r,X+Y=r+s)}{P(X+Y=r+s)}\\
&=\frac{P(X=r,Y=s)}{P(X+Y=r+s)} \\
&=\frac{P(X=r)P(Y=s)}{P(X+Y=r+s)}
\end{align}

Are you able to complete it?

Comment: According to question it is quite easy to see that the parameters of $X+Y$ are $m,n$but $p$ is a common parameter of $X,Y$ why not it should be a parameter of $X+Y$.thanks.

Comment: $X+Y$ follows binomial distribution $Bin(m+n, p)$

Comment: The Goh how can $P(X=r\cap X+Y=r+s)=P(X=r,Y=s)$.please explain.thanks.

Comment: If $X=r$ and $X+Y=r+s$, subtract the first equation from the second equation would reduce the problem to $X=r$ and $Y=s$.

Comment: The Goh but sir$X=r$ and $X+Y=r+s$ are two separate binomial distribution and we have go in for intersection of these two.although $x$ and $ y$ are independent but $x$ and $x+y$ are not.how do you know that intersection of these binomial distributions are just subtraction.please explain more clearly,sir.thanks.

Comment: Imagine someone tosses a coin $n+m$ times. He denotes the number of heads for the first $n$ tosses as $X$ and denotes the number of heads for the remaining $m$ tosses as $Y$. He recorded the outcome for $X$ and the outcome for $X+Y$ (that is total number of heads). can you recover the value of $Y$?

Comment: yes that's for sure,but I didn't have trouble in finding out value of $Y$.by the definition of conditional probability taught in my school,$P(X|Y)=P(X \cap Y)/P(Y)$.here. In This question also my doubt is as to why $P(X=r|X+Y=r+s)$ is equal to $P(X=r,Y=s)$ or how can $P(X=r \cap X+Y=r+s)=P(X=r,Y=s)$.thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46838/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-navinstudent).

Comment: how can use chat in my android mobile app.the link is directing me to the browser

Comment: I don't use mobile app. So I'm not sure. It's good to use chat so that the comment is not too long. $P(X = r \cap X+Y=r+s) = P(X=r, Y=s)$ The other equality is not true.

Comment: but that's the inequality you used in your post.

Comment: There is no inequality in my post. There are 3 equalities, which one do you don't get it?